# Sum of the numbers in a row (VBA in Word)

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word

Good day!
There is a problem:
Selected piece of text. In the allocation is as follows:
 ,  .
Example: book 100, pencil 20, ...
I would like to find the sum of the numbers in the row and write it at the end, that is,
book 100, the handle 20
$ 120
I'm trying to solve this problem, but does not go ...
It is unclear, for example, how to access the character in the string.
Did so:

```
While i <> EndOfText
Char = Mid (AllSelectionText, i, 1)
If Char> = "0" And Char <= "9" Then
...
End If
i = i 1
Wend
```

But it is not very nice ... must have a function like string (i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using regular expressions?  You would need to add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5, and then you could use the following (not tested):

```
Function sumOfNumbersInText(text As String) As Long

Dim rgx As New RegExp  'creates a new instance of the Regular Expression object
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim mtch As Match
Dim sum As Long

sum = 0
rgx.Pattern = "\d+"  'pattern for a sequence of digits
rgx.Global = True    'find all matches within text
Set matches = rgx.Execute(text) 'get collection of all substrings matching the pattern
For Each mtch In matches
    sum = sum + CLng(mtch.Value) 'change each substring into a number and add to sum
Next

sumOfNumbersInText = sum

End Function
```

Comment: Dear, sigil!
You did it so fast and it's work!!!!
I want to understand it, so could add some comments for you code or 
give a link to book\site where I could read something about it?
This is brilliant!!!

Comment: For other who need it:
reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
(Tools - References)

Comment: I just added some comments to my code.  I usually use [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) as my reference for regular expressions, and special restrictions on using regexp in VBA can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html).  Tutorial [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).